# Validate selection of at least one checkbox using model rules. Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, validationrules

I am using the following code to validate that I have at least one checkbox selected but I have a problem.

JS

```
$("#btn_enviar").click(function() {

    var invalido = 0;
    $(".item").each(function( ) {
       if ($(this).find("select").val() == 1) {
         var cont = 0;
         $(this).find("input:checkbox, input:radio").each(function() {

              if($(this).is(":checked")){
                  cont++;
              }

         });
       }
       if(cont < 1){
           $(this).find(".text-error-check").show();
           $(this).find(".dynamicform_inner").css({
              "border": "2px solid #dd4b39",
              "background-color": "white"
            });

            invalido = 1;
        }
    });
```

});
');

For example, if I send the data first without having a selected checkbox it works for me but it ignores the other validations of the rules and I only get the selection error, if I then select a checkbox and send the data again, the validations of the rules of the model work.

**First send**

[image]

**Second send**

[image]

I have tried to do it with the rules in my model but have not been successful. How can I include it together with the other rules of the model?

P.D: I am using the dynamic form to generate the checkboxes and inputs.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209265/yii2-validate-if-at-least-one-checkbox-is-selected, This seems to be similar problem with yours.

Comment: Please post a request from browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

**Model rules**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // an inline validator defined as the model method checkSelection()
            ['checkboxes', 'checkSelection'],
        ...
        ];
    }

public function checkSelection($attribute, $params, $validator)
{
    $error = true;
    foreach ($this->checkboxes as $checkbox) {
        //if at least 1 checkbox is checked then we skip error.
        if ($checkbox) {
            $error = false;
        }
    }
    if ($error) {
        $this->addError('checkboxes', 'You must select at least one checkbox to continue');
    }
};
```

Comment: I've been trying to apply this method but it didn't work for me.

Comment: can you post your `ajax request` in the question?

Comment: Is the jquery I use published or what part are you referring to?